# Webscraping: Separating phrases from HTML text output in python

Tags: html, web-scraping, spacing

Im learning web scraping for apartments. The HTML block for one apartment looks like this:

**Input**

```
# Create a web search and save the results
base = 'https://www.booli.se/'
addition = 'kungsholmen,vasastan,gardet/115353,115349,115347'
url = base+addition
print(url)
notar = requests.get(url) # load the webpage content
page = notar.content # get the url content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml') # convert it to a beautiful soup object

links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('/annons/'))
```

**Output**

```
<a class="elVgu" href="/annons/4387774" rel="noopener
noreferrer" target="_blank"><div class="_2x4yP _1Pdm1 nhG4K">
<div class="VvVg1"><picture><source sizes="(min-width: 460px)
959px, (min-width: 991px) 459px, 459px"
srcset="//bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_796x0.webp 796w,
  //bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_360x0.webp 360w,
  //bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_270x0.webp 270w" type="image/webp"/><source sizes="(min-width: 460px) 959px, (min-width: 991px) 459px, 459px" srcset="//bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_796x0.jpg 796w,
  //bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_270x0.jpg 360w,
  //bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_270x0.jpg 270w" type="image/jpeg"/><img alt="Öppnar information om bostaden i ny tab" class="TNXq2" loading="lazy" src="//bcdn.se/images/cache/27006816_270x0.jpg"/></picture>
<div class="_1Aa76"><p class="_1Csan">Balkong</p><p 
class="_1Csan">Eldstad</p></div></div><div class="_1bIS9"><h3
 class="_3R27q">Tomtebogatan 5B</h3></div><div class="_1bIS9">
<p class="_3HprD">4 895 000 kr</p></div><div class="_2ZDKS">
<div class="_2iD1Y"><div class="_1cru3 _2epd7"><div
 class="_1jUwL _36W0F _2MiJJ">Värdering</div><div class="MsC3E _36W0F _2MiJJ">5 470 000 kr</div><hr class="_2DJbA _2F2SG"/></div></div></div><div class="_3IN5U"><strong><p>Vasastan -
 Birkastan</p></strong><p>Lägenhet</p><p>2 rum</p><p>52 m²</p>
<p>931 kr/mån</p></div></div></a>
```

When I access the text of each HTML block / each apartment then the text comes, but all together, without spacing in-between. The words are different for every apartment, as is the order of the phrases (the features comes first and it could be 0-5 features, which makes an order method invalid) and I would like to be able to save the name, price, features etc. into a table.

**Input**

```
for nr_aps, row in enumerate(links):
    row.str
    info = row.text # show each apartment info
    print(info) 
    print('')
```

**Output**

```
BalkongEldstadTomtebogatan 5B4 895 000 krVärdering5 470 000 krVasastan - BirkastanLägenhet2 rum52 m²931 kr/mån
```

Do you have any idea of how to save each section to a table? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are saving all the appartment info into one variable "info".

If you want to just print the appartment one at a time just use

```
print(row.text)
```

Or simply just add \n to make a new line

```
info = row.text + "\n"
```